# Installing OpenManage on Ubuntu - Login Failed

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, installation

Server: Dell R510
RAID Controller: PERC 6/i
OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Problem:
I need to add 3 additional drives to a RAID 5 array. If I understand correctly, this cannot be accomplished from the BIOS with the PERC 6/i controller, but must instead be accomplished from Dell OpenManage.

I've followed the directions at http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/deb/latest/ in order to install OpenManage on the server. However, whenever I attempt to login from a web browser, it says "Login Failed." I've edited /opt/dell/srvadmin/etc/omarolemap as instructed, and have tried logging in with multiple users (including root). Nothing works.

Question:
Has anyone encountered this problem, or does anyone know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the /etc/pam.d/ for an  omauth file and move it somewhere else or delete the file.  I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and upgraded to OpenManager 7.1 but could not login till I removed that file in pam.d.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, you just saved me the headache of reinstalling the OS.